# Show button in Django template only when the file is selected through check box?

Tags: javascript, django, templates

I am getting the check box dynamically in Django template like this:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" /></td>
              <td><label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.file_name }}</label></td>
```

There's a unshare button like this:

```
<button>Unshare</button>
```

I want to show the `Unshare` button only when the user clicks on check-box.

Comment: Are you using jquery or do you need a pure js solution?

Comment: can you give more details of the html (depending on the relative position of the checkbox and button, a css3 solution might be possible)

Comment: I am not using Jquery. I was thinking if that's possible with Django if..else statement.

Comment: You won't be able to do this without client side code. Once django has rendered the page you'll need javascript to handle any events that don't result in a new http request (page load). Does the button show once any one of the checkboxes is checked or is there a button for every checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly add some more id's to your template so that you can identify elements.

```
<table id="choices">
{% for choice in choices %}
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" /></td>
    <td><label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.file_name }}</label></td>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Then give the button an id and an inline style -

`<button id="unshare_button" style="display: none;">Unshare</button>`

Then use the following javascript (this shows the button as soon as any one of the 
checkboxes is clicked - it doesn't hide the button if they're unchecked).

```
var choices_table = document.getElementByID('choices');
var checkboxes = choices_table.getElementsByTagName('input');
var unshare_button = document.getElementByID('unshare_button');
for (var i = checkboxes.length; i > 0; i--) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        unshare_button.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

I'm afraid I haven't checked this code, but it should give you an idea.